# apk icon not shown on other devices

Tags: android, icons, apk

I recently created an android application with a custom made icon. I signed the app and shared the APK. The app is not displaying the custom icon on other devices but my device has the custom made image as the icon. I don't understand what is happen ing.

Comment: Please share some more details. We can't help you if you are too vague in explaining your problem

Comment: @GaneshKalal I wanted to know why the custom made icon for my app is shown only on my mobile and not on other mobiles with whom I have shared the release apk.

Comment: have you added the icons for all resolutions or just for 1 resolution?

Comment: All the resolutions but have stored in my drawable folder. Should I move them back to mipmap?

Comment: Yeah you should do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your project goto -> res -> right click on mipmap -> new -> image asset -> under Source asset change path and select your image path ->next -> finish -> and in manifest add bellow code

```
    android:icon="@drawable/generated_image_name"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/generated_image_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```